# How can I have multiple instances of this jQuery image slide effect on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now I have this on my page:

```
<section class="image_slider grid_4">
<nav class="slider_nav"> <a href="#" class="left">&nbsp;</a> <a href="#" class="right">&nbsp;</a> </nav>
<div class="slides">
    <a href="/images/placeholders/800x600/7.jpg" rel="fancybox_gallery1"><img src="/images/placeholders/300x200/7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="/images/placeholders/800x600/8.jpg" rel="fancybox_gallery1"><img src="/images/placeholders/300x200/8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

The js that controls that is this:

```
/* Sidebar image slider */
$('.image_slider').each(function () {

    /* Functions */
    function resetInterval () {
        clearInterval(imageSliderInterval);
        imageSliderInterval = setInterval(next, 4000);
    }
    function next () {
        $('.image_slider .slides').children(':last').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).prependTo('.image_slider .slides').fadeIn(1);
        });
    }
    function previous () {
        $('.image_slider .slides').children(':last').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).prependTo('.image_slider .slides').fadeIn(1);
        });
    }

    /* Initialize */
    var imageSliderInterval;
    resetInterval();

    /* Controls */
    $('.image_slider .left').click(function () {
        next();
        resetInterval();
    });
    $('.image_slider .right').click(function () {
        previous();
        resetInterval();
    });

});
```

Any ideas how I can have multiple instances of the image slide show, with separate controls on each image gallery?

The original code came from this template if you want to take a look in the flesh - scroll down to the header "Nam imperdiet lacinia":

http://travel.equiet.sk/hotel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should insulate instances. The key for situations like this is defining the current main element using `this` within the `each` loop and using `find()` within main element to localize search for other elements to current instance only.

```
/* Sidebar image slider */
$('.image_slider').each(function () {

    var $slider=$(this), $slides= $slider.find('.slides'), imageSliderInterval;

    /* Functions */
    function resetInterval () {
        clearInterval(imageSliderInterval);
        imageSliderInterval = setInterval(next, 4000);
    }
    function next () {
        $slides.children(':last').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).prependTo($slides).fadeIn(1);
        });
    }
    function previous () {
        $slides.children(':last').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).prependTo($slides).fadeIn(1);
        });
    }

    /* Initialize */

    resetInterval();

    /* Controls */
    $slider.find('.left').click(function () {
        next();
        resetInterval();
    });
    $slider.find('.right').click(function () {
        previous();
        resetInterval();
    });

});
```

Comment: Bloody hell - it worked first time and works well! Can't thank you enough. A whole night of head scratching avoided! Cheers mate. James

Comment: remember this pattern... very common for multiple widget instances..glad it worked out